# Python behaviour I can't understand

Tags: python, project, barcode

I am doing a project for school that needs to search a database (csv) for products. It does this by matching a verified EAN-8 code to the 0th column of each row, scanned in a for loop. There is a try, except that tries to match the code, and then display the product, except for if it can't find it, when it's meant to print "PRODUCT NOT FOUND, TRY AGAIN". I have tried different iterations of if, else, if, elif combined by try, except but to no avail. Please help.

```
#code is the barcode
        for row in csv_file:
            try:
                if code == row[0]:
                    print("This product is: ", row[1], "\n", "Quantity left in stock: ", row[2], "\n", "Cost: ", row[3], "\n")
                    quant = int(input("How many do you you want?: "))
                    if quant > int(row[2]):
                        print("We don't have that many, try again")
                        order()
                    else:
                        orderrow = row
                        orderrow[2] = quant
                        orderrow[3] = float(orderrow[3]) * quant
                        totalcost = totalcost + orderrow[3]
                        orderlist.append(orderrow)


            except:
                print("ITEM NOT FOUND, TRY AGAIN")
                order()
```

Comment: What exception are you expecting that `except` to catch?

Comment: Well clearly you're not getting any exception.  I think you're misunderstanding what `try/except` actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to set a variable when you find a matching row. After the loop is done, check the variable to see if anything was found, and if not you print the message.

```
found = false
for row in csv_file:
    if code == row[0]:
        found = true
        print("This product is: ", row[1], "\n", "Quantity left in stock: ", row[2], "\n", "Cost: ", row[3], "\n")
        quant = int(input("How many do you you want?: "))
        if quant > int(row[2]):
            print("We don't have that many, try again")
            order()
        else:
            orderrow = row
            orderrow[2] = quant
            orderrow[3] = float(orderrow[3]) * quant
            totalcost = totalcost + orderrow[3]
            orderlist.append(orderrow)
if !found
    print("ITEM NOT FOUND, TRY AGAIN")
    order()
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar this really helped!

Answer (score 5):

You need a proper `if-else`, not a `try-catch`. There is no `Exception` to be caught here. How about:

```
for row in csv_file:
    if code == row[0]:
        print("This product is: ", row[1], "\n", "Quantity left in stock: ", row[2], "\n", "Cost: ", row[3], "\n")
        quant = int(input("How many do you you want?: "))
        if quant > int(row[2]):
            print("We don't have that many, try again")
            order()
        else:
            orderrow = row
            orderrow[2] = quant
            orderrow[3] = float(orderrow[3]) * quant
            totalcost = totalcost + orderrow[3]
            orderlist.append(orderrow)
    else:
        print("ITEM NOT FOUND, TRY AGAIN")
        order()
```

Comment: This will print `ITEM NOT FOUND` for every line in the file that doesn't have the matching code.

Comment: @Barmar I haven't validated OP's logic. Just fixed the unnecessary `try-except` and pointed towards an `if-else`. Looks like that's all OP needs at this point :)

Comment: Edited my comment. Thanks